# Error "this.push not a function" angular Foreach

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I get this error when i execute my function "`this.push is not a function`" what is causing it? this is not my first time to use the `Angular forEach` and `this.push`

```
$scope.search_subCategory_businesses= function()
        {
            alert("tigidi tigidi subcategory");
            //$scope.busi_es = sharedProperties.getProperty();
            $scope.busi_es=JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("biz"));
            window.localStorage.removeItem("biz");
            console.log("sharedProperty hahahaah is",$scope.busi_es);

            angular.forEach($scope.busi_es,function(value,key)
            {
                            $scope.business = value;

                            if($scope.business.logo == '' || $scope.business.logo==null)
                            {
                                $scope.business.logo=config.BaseImageURL+"uploads/defbanner.png"
                            }else
                            {
                                $scope.business.logo=config.BaseImageURL+$scope.business.logo;
                            }
                            this.push($scope.business); //complaings

            },$scope.businesses);
            //return $scope.businesses;

        };
        $scope.search_subCategory_businesses();
```

Comment: make sure `$scope.businesses` is an array.

Comment: are you using `strict mode`?

Comment: `console.log(this)` and make sure `$scope.businesses` is same type so it can fit.

Comment: @MarkoCen thanks i had messed up the $scope.businesses variable